# First ZF axiom.

Tags: set-theory

The first ZF axiom states: $(A = B) \iff ((x\in A)\iff(x\in B))$. The question is: can I use conjunction instead of double implication there between statements about X's? So, does this whole expression above is the same as the following: $(A=B)\iff((x\in A) \wedge (x\in B))$? It's difficult to me to grasp the first one that is used in textbooks. 
If these two expression are not the same, then please explain why. And also explain why is the first one is exactly what we are looking for when defining the equality between sets. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: No, conjunction $A\land B$ is not double implication $A\leftrightarrow B$.  You can see this when $v(A)=v(B)=\bot$.

Comment: I'm not sure why this has a vote to close - what additional context seems necessary? (The one quibble I have is that "the first ZF axiom" is a bit unclear -  there's no canonical ordering of the axioms, and one should just say "the axiom of extensionality" instead - but it's clear from the rest of the sentence what axiom is meant.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**These are quite different**.

First of all, what you've written isn't really what you want: you're forgetting the universal quantifiers. The extensionality axiom is $$\forall A,B(A=B\iff \forall x(x\in A\iff x\in B)).$$ At this point it should be clear that we can't replace the second "$\iff$" with a "$\wedge$," since if we do we get $$\forall A,B(A=B\iff \forall x(x\in A\wedge x\in B)).$$

(intuitively: "Two sets are equal iff each contains *everything*").

And this is clearly silly: for example, we get $\{5\}\not=\{5\}$, since taking $x=2$ we have that $x\in \{5\}\wedge x\in \{5\}$ *fails*.

There is a way to phrase extensionality in terms of conjunction, though: it's $$\forall A,B(A=B\iff \forall x((x\in A\wedge x\in B)\vee (x\not\in A\wedge x\not\in B))).$$ But this is just a translation of $\iff$, since $$p\iff q$$ is the same as $$(p\wedge q)\vee (\neg p\wedge\neg q).$$

Comment: Thank you. Now it seems that I understand.

Comment: Hi again. I am a little bit confused. For example, for ∀A,B(A=B⟺∀x(x∈A⟺x∈B)) if I take x = 4 and A = B= {1,2,3} then substituting the x, it will look like (4 ∈ A ⟺4 ∈ B) ⟺ A=B  ;  expanding: (4 ∈ A ⇒ 4 ∈ B) ∧ ( 4 ∈ B ⇒ 4 ∈ A) ⟺ A=B; which simplifies to (False ⇒ False) ∧ (False ⇒ False) ⟺ A=B ; True ∧ True ⟺ A=B.



So as far as I understand, if we substitute x with the value that is not in our sets, then we still yield that A = B, right? 
Thank you.

Comment: by the way, is it hard to learn axiomatic set theory without first knowing naive set theory?